# How to change qmake PREFIX location

Tags: linux, qt, makefile, qmake

I used below commands to install some stuff.

```
qmake PREFIX=/path/to/my/dir
make
make install
```

However the path I gave was wrong, how do I update PREFIX to the right location and remove the old install, then install again?

I tried:

```
rm -rf /path/to/my/dir/bin    # this is where the program being installed
qmake PREFIX=/path/to/correct/dir
make
make install
```

But it's still being installed to the old path.

Comment: Try removing the `qmake`-generated **Makefile** files, and then run `qmake` again with the corrected path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to "qmake -h", this would set it globally:

`qmake -set prefix /path/to/correct/dir`

Comment: That's already been answered:
`rm -rf /path/to/my/dir/bin    # this is where the program being installed`

Comment: It's might be important, this command must be issued with out any other command parameters as suggested here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/4479/how-to-use-set-option-in-qmake

Answer (score 10):

For ~ QT 5:

In `qmake` the installation directory for the standard installation rules comes from the `qmake` variable `target.path`.

In general, `qmake` does not use a setting called `PREFIX`, although because this is the traditional term in Unix for the target installation directory, it is a popular enough convention for particular projects to create their own `PREFIX` variable for use within their project files (`*.pro`).

Take a look through the `.pro` files of the project and find out where `target.path` is set. If it is set from an environment variable, i.e.

```
target.path = $$(PREFIX)  # note the regular parentheses
```

then you can pass the value in the environment you run `qmake` in:

```
$ PREFIX=/path/to/my/dir qmake
```

If it is set from a [`qmake` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html#properties), i.e.

```
target.path = $$[PREFIX]  # note the square brackets
```

then you can set the property persistently for future `qmake` runs on the command line:

```
$ qmake -set PREFIX /path/to/my/dir
```

If it is set from an internal variable, it will look like

```
target.path = $$PREFIX
```

or

```
target.path = $${PREFIX}  # note the curly braces
```

There's no way to override the value of an internal variable from the `qmake` command line; you need to figure out where in the `.pro` file the internal variable is being set and make appropriate changes, perhaps by just editing the `.pro` file, or if there is some kind of logic there, figuring out how to have it choose a different value.

Comment: What if it is set in square brackets like `$$[PREFIX]`? Do you then use `qmake -set PREFIX VALUE` to set the value?

Comment: @pooya13 I added a section for that case, and yeah, that's a qmake property, so you can set it from the command line like that.